# Resolve DNS command returns different IP addresses

Tags: domain-name-system, failovercluster, resolve

I have a failover cluster with two nodes. Both machines are ESXi VM with two network adapters: first one public and the second one is private. When I trying to resolve DNS name for any of node I receive mix of IP addresses (there are public and private IP):

[image]

Both nodes have registered in DNS manager as hosts with public only IP:

[image]

Why resolve DNS command returns different IP addresses?

Answer (score 1):

I think, it use [Round Robin DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS)

> In its simplest implementation, Round-robin DNS works by responding to DNS requests not only with a single potential IP address, but with one out of a list of potential IP addresses corresponding to several servers that host identical services. The order in which IP addresses from the list are returned is the basis for the term round robin. With each DNS response, the IP address sequence in the list is permuted. Usually, basic IP clients attempt connections with the first address returned from a DNS query, so that on different connection attempts, clients would receive service from different providers, thus distributing the overall load among servers.

Comment: I have disabled "RoundRobin DNS" then rebooted DNS server and got the same result. Resolve DNS command still returns different IP addresses

Answer (score 0):

The powershell module does not only use dns unless specified. it uses any resolution method including nebios, hosts, etc.

don't use shortages, use terminated FQDN

`host.example.com.`